# How to install a GTK theme?

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell, gtk

newbie here. I'll keep it short.

I've been trying to install this GTK theme

https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1436585but

But it won't let me choose it no matter how much I tried. I've done the following:

- Installing tweaks and user themes extensions
- Creating .themes file
- Putting it in the actual themes file (computer>usr>share>themes)

But after doing all of those things, it doesn't even recognize the theme and won't let me choose it in tweaks. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I'm completely burnout at this point so might as well let someone else do the thinking for me if you're so kind.

My current OS is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

My current GNOME is 42.5

Please be patient with me, I only downloaded Ubuntu today and Linux is really new to me but I'm really excited to be starting out with it! Any help will be apreciated, cheers.

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
GNOME is 42.5
I tagged unity cuz I thought it would reach more people that way. Imma fix a couple things about this post anyways but those are my versions right now.

Comment: It's all better now, do you have any idea what this could be?

Comment: Hi @Mirko, have you tried copying the extracted folder to ~/.themes?

Comment: I have. Still wont recognize it on the gnome shells option or icons or anything

Comment: what is included in the Infinity theme's folder? There may be separate sub-folders that need to moved to the correct locations.